# Disable ALL CSS on mobile

Tags: html, css

Hi I would like to know how to disable a whole CSS3 stylesheet in either HTML or CSS. My css is almost all animations, so I would just like to know how to disable to whole thing

Comment: Stick the css in a media query, E.g. `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { ..css..}`

Comment: How would you determine if the user is on a mobile? What about tablets? If you're happy to pick an arbitrary size then you could just wrap the lot in a [media-query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) otherwise you're gonna have to do some dirty browser sniffing.

Comment: I had to switch max to min but it still worked. Thank you for helping @moob didn't see you. I only want it on mobile phones. I want tablets to see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using a JS library like `Modernizr` you can do the following :

```
if ( Modernizr.touch ) {
    // if mobile device disable stylesheets
    for ( i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        void(document.styleSheets.item(i).disabled=true);
    }
}
```

I don't think you can be 100% sure whether it is mobile device or not

Comment: It's for a social site that doesn't allow JS so I'm trying to work purely in css

Comment: then i guess your best bet would be doing it server side..